# dart throw fake stacktrace in a test

Tags: dart

Is it possible to throw a fake stack trace in dart?
For example, I have this code:

```
      final FakeStartContext startContext = FakeStartContext(
        runOverride: () async => throw Exception(fakeError),
      );
```

It is overriding a function by throwing a fake exceptionMsg to it. Is there a way to throw a fake stack trace in addition to the fake error as well? Like something similar to this:

```
      final FakeStartContext startContext = FakeStartContext(
        runOverride: () async => throw Exception(fakeError, fakeStackTrace),
      );
```

Such that it could be caught by `catch(err, stacktrace)`?

Comment: Why do you want a fake StackTrace?

Comment: I have a widget that paints errors and stack traces differently, and I would like to test if the part that paints the stack traces work properly.

Comment: Try https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/StackTrace/StackTrace.fromString.html ?

Comment: You'll need the [`Error.throwWithStackTrace`](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/commit/20e9582106c89ed80883c9e515349ec52c2ff690) function coming with Dart 2.16.  Also see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/30741.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, because your code is asynchronous:

```dart
final FakeStartContext startContext = FakeStartContext(
  runOverride: () async => 
      await Future.error(Exception(fakeError), fakeStackTrace),
);
```

or just

```dart
final FakeStartContext startContext = FakeStartContext(
  runOverride: () => Future.error(Exception(fakeError), fakeStackTrace),
);
```

It's not currently possible to do the same thing in a synchronous setting.
It doesn't help to to create a future containing your fake stack trace, because you can't wait for that future synchronously.

As mentioned, an `Error.throwWithStackTrace(error, stack)` function is scheduled to be added in Dart 2.16, which can synchronously throw an object and a stack trace of your choice.

Comment: How do I initialize a `fakeStackTrace`?

Comment: I found a way: `StackTrace.fromString('Fake stacktrace')`

Answer (score 0):

Why use a fake stacktrace when you can easily get a real one?

For example:

```dart
thrower() {
  ghi() => throw Exception('error');
  def() => ghi();
  abc() => def();
  abc();
}

void main() {
  try {
    thrower();
  } catch (e, st) {
    print('Error $e, StackTrace: $st');
  }
}
```

This will print something like this on Dart VM:

```
Error Exception: error, StackTrace: #0      thrower.ghi (file:///Users/renato/example.dart:2:12)
#1      thrower.def (file:///Users/renato/example.dart:3:15)
#2      thrower.abc (file:///Users/renato/example.dart:4:15)
#3      thrower (file:///Users/renato/example.dart:5:6)
#4      main (file:///Users/renato/example.dart:10:5)
#5      _delayEntrypointInvocation.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:283:19)
#6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
```

On [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/?null_safety=true) (JS) it prints this instead:

```
Error Exception: error, StackTrace: wrapException@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:363:17
throwExpression@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:377:15
call$0@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:3040:16
call$0@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:3046:23
call$0@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:3052:23
thrower@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:272:65
main@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:277:11
@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:3217:15
@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:3200:15
dartProgram@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:3211:5
@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame_dark.html line 19 > injectedScript:3219:3
replaceJavaScript@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame.js:19:19
messageHandler@https://dartpad.dev/scripts/frame.js:140:30
```